# Starting ngrok and python app on startup

Tags: python, linux, unix, cron, ngrok

I am currently running [ngrock](https://ngrok.com/) and a python app concurrently on a specific port to text my raspberry pi, and have it respond accordingly to my message via [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/). Each time my raspberry pi boots up, or reboots, I need to manually start the services again with `./ngrok http 5000` and `python /path/to/file/app.py`. To avoid that, I edited my cron jobs as follows, and wrote a script called `startService.py`. However, it doesn't seem to be functioning properly, as I do not receive answers to texts after reboot. Any ideas?

Cron:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/5 * * * * python /rasp/system/systemCheck.py
@reboot python /Rasp/system/twilio/startService.py &
```

startService.py

```
import os
os.system('/./ngrok http -subdomain=ABC123  5000')
os.system('python /Rasp/system/twilio/starter/app.py')
```

Comment: Does this have to be run as root?  If so, then you have to use `sudo crontab -e` to set the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple failed attempts I have seem to come up with a working system. I first had to authorize the `root` user to use my ngrok account by doing the following:

```
sudo su
./ngrok authtoken {{Insert Your Auth Token Here}}
exit
```

Then, I created ngrokLauncher.sh and appLauncher.sh as shown.

ngrokLauncher.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh

cd /
./ngrok http -subdomain={{My Reserved Subdomain}} 5000 &
cd /
```

appLauncher.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh

cd /Storage/system/twilio/starter
python app.py &
cd /
```

Then, I modified the file permissions so they would be able to be run on startup `sudo chmod 755 ngrokLauncher.sh && sudo chmod 755 appLauncher.sh`. Lastly, I edited the Cron Jobs as follows:

Crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/5 * * * * python /SKYNET/system/systemCheck.py
@reboot sh /Storage/ngrokLauncher.sh >/Storage/logs/cronlog 2>&1
@reboot sh /Storage/appLauncher.sh >/Storage/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

Then after running `sudo reboot`, the system restarted and I received a response to my sms from the python app.

Comment: Why not use upstart?

Comment: where to save the .sh file? and what script to fire up the sh file?

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention your OS, assuming your OS using Upstart for boot you can create upstart script to start then your process will automatically spawn at boot or when the process die. For ngrok, create a file /etc/init/ngrok.conf

```
# Ngrok
#
# Create tunnel provided by ngrok.io

description "Ngrok Tunnel"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
umask 022

exec /ngrok http -subdomain={{My Reserved Subdomain}} 5000
```

Now it will automaticlaly start at boot. If you want to start manually just issue command.

```
$ sudo service ngrok start
```

Just for suggestion, putting your binary on root directory / is not good practice.

Reference:
http://notes.rioastamal.net/2016/05/starting-ngrok-automatically-at-boot.html

Comment: What about passing parameters to `start` like `start --all`, so it could pick up **ngrok.yml** file?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, by default ngrok will read config from $HOME/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml, to read the ngrok.yml other than default path you can use -config when executing ngrok application. 

`exec /ngrok http -config=/my/config/ngrok.yml -subdomain={{My Reserved Subdomain}} 5000`

See https://ngrok.com/docs#config-location

Comment: No, ngrok does not read **all** subdomains by default unless you tell it to.

Comment: In case of `Failed to start ngrok.service: Unit ngrok.service not found.` here is the solution: [python - Failed to start <myapp>.service: Unit <myapp>.service not found - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891050/failed-to-start-myapp-service-unit-myapp-service-not-found)